# The big O notation

Tags: big-o, notation

I am reading about Big O notation. In the book I have, there is an example in which the complexity of *n<sup>2</sup>* is in class of O(*n<sup>3</sup>*). That doesn't seem logical to me because *n<sup>3</sup>* depends on *n* and it isn't just a plain constant multiplier that we can "get rid of."

Please explain to me why those two are of the same complexity. I can't find an answer on this forum or any other.

Comment: Does the book mean that *the operation* `n * n` is of complexity class O(n^3), or that the two *complexity classes* O(n^2) and O(n^3) are the same?

Comment: The first one.. the n*n is of complexity class of O(n^3)

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail what example you have found.

Comment: This is one of the examples for definition: f(n)<=c*g(n).

Comment: Check out [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) - they're more suited to this type of question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have that in mind when i ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big O determines an upper bound for large values of n. O(*n<sup>3</sup>*) is larger than O(*n<sup>2</sup>*) and so an *n<sup>2</sup>* program is still O(*n<sup>3</sup>*). It's also O(*n<sup>4</sup>*), O(*n<sup>5</sup>), ..., O(*n<sup>infinity</sup>*).

The reverse is not true, however. An n^3 program is not O(*n<sup>2</sup>*). Rather it would be Omega(*n<sup>2</sup>*), as Omega determines a lower bound (how much work we have to do at least).

Big O says nothing of this upper bound being "tight", it just needs to be higher than the actual complexity. So while an n*n complexity program is bounded by O(*n<sup>3</sup>*), that's not a very tight bound. O(*n<sup>2</sup>*) is tighter and more informative.

Comment: So, if an algorithm is n*n complex, the closest class of complexity is O(n*n) but because it can't go any faster it can't be of O(n) class or lower but can go up?

Comment: @user1932153 yes, I've edited the post to address that question.

Comment: In the standard notation, Theta is not a lower bound, Omega is. A function f(n) = Θ(g(n)) when f(n) = O(g(n)) and f(n) = Ω(g(n))